# Thymleaf , loading fragments using jQuery

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm checking Thymeleaf with Spring these days. I came across a question on fragments. I've written a Spring controller using `@Controller` and there is a method `@PostMapping` below is the method

```
@PostMapping(value="/xxx/yyy/add",consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody AModel addMethod(@Valid @RequestBody AModel aModel, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

I've used `$.ajax` method to POST data to /xxx/yyy/add URL. JSON is mapped ith the AModel object and it works. But I'm returning an `AModel` object as json response. Not a string mentioning the thymeleaf fragment. The thymeleaf fragment I'm trying to reload contains a table of data. Could someone point me at the right direction of how this could be done? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing return type to String?

Comment: That's the thing @SupunDharmarathne, most examples have that approach. But there are some additional data that I need to refer in the `aModel` object. So I'm trying to find a way to do it without rewriting the DOM via jQuery.

Comment: If the json response contains the table data, will it be ok?

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne currently no, it doesn''t. I'm trying to find a way to load Thymeleaf fragments without setting the controller method return type as String.

Comment: see my below answer :) hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
private ResponseBody test( HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse )
{
    Response response = new Response<String>();
    WebContext webContext = new WebContext( httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, servletContext );



    response.setData( generateTemplate( webContext, viewResolver, "fragmentpath") );
    response.setMessage( "Success" );
    response.setStatus(SUCCESS );

    return response;

}

  public static String generateTemplate( WebContext ctx, ViewResolver viewResolver, String baseTemplate)
{

    TemplateEngine engine = ( ( ThymeleafViewResolver ) viewResolver ).getTemplateEngine();

    String renderedHtml = engine.process( baseTemplate, ctx );
    return renderedHtml;

}
```