# Return a thymeleaf view conditionally with PDF view in Spring MVC handler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-validator

I am developing a spring boot application & using spring validation. Need to return a thymeleaf page if any error occurs after validation.

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping(params = "_action_preview_pdf", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getTemplatePDF(@Valid @ModelAttribute(COMMAND_NAME) RxTemplateConfiguration configuration,
                                             BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return VIEW_FORM;  //Error
    }

    ....

    return new ResponseEntity<>(prescriptionHelper.getTemplatePdf(configuration), headers, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

getting following error:

`error: return VIEW_FORM;
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to ResponseEntity<byte[]>`

Here, `VIEW_FORM = "config-form"` which is a thymeleaf page.
How can I return thymeleaf page?

Comment: You could always throw an exception and let your `@ControllerAdvice` class handle the response

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I need to return page with error message. From your comment I understand that in this way it is not possible to return a page.

Comment: Your `@ControllerAdvice` class **can** return a page, that's what I'm saying. Trying to work the template renderer into a `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` seems prohibitively difficult. See https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#controller-based-exception-handling

Comment: Is it obvious for you to return `ResponseEntity<byte[]>`? If the requirement is to return `pdf` view, there exist other elegant solutions.

Comment: Instead of error page, try returning response which contains per-rendered page. see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481703/thymleaf-loading-fragments-using-jquery/50483239#50483239

Comment: @Shafin Mahmud. the requirement is to return pdf view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Removed `@ResponseBody` tag.
2. Replaced return type from `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` to `Object`

Code after update:

```
@PostMapping(params = "_action_preview_pdf", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public Object getTemplatePDF(@Valid @ModelAttribute(COMMAND_NAME) RxTemplateConfiguration configuration,
                                         BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return VIEW_FORM;  //Error fixed.
    }

    ....

    return new ResponseEntity<>(prescriptionHelper.getTemplatePdf(configuration), headers, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are returning `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` from a handler there is no way to return with *view-name* too. If you want you to generate a *PDF* view along with conditional other views there are several ways for doing this. I prefer to do this with `BeanNameViewResolver` with `itexpdf` library

### BeanNameViewResolver

This resolves Views declared as beans. That means you can use a View's bean name as a view name. In Spring Boot, BeanNameViewResolver bean is registered by default. And to generate a PDF view from bean you need this `iText API`. add this in your `build.gradle`

```
compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itext7-core', version: '7.1.3'
```

To occupy `BeanNameViewResolver` you need to create a bean extending `AbstratView` where you will use the *itex7* for generating PDF document.

```
@Component("reportView")
public class HelloPdfView extends AbstractView {

    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request,
                                           HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myReport.pdf");

        // get your bean for generating pdf say it is Report
        Report report = (Report) model.get("report");

        //use IText API
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(response.getOutputStream());
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(pdf);

        //do other customization you like
        Paragraph title = new Paragraph(report.getName());
        title.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA));
        title.setFontSize(18f);
        title.setItalic();
        pdfDocument.add(title);


        //content
        Paragraph content = new Paragraph(report.getContent());
        pdfDocument.add(content);

        pdfDocument.close();

    }
}
```

Now when you just call it from controller as other views

```
@PostMapping("/report")
public String showPdf(@Valid @ModelAttribute(COMMAND_NAME) RxTemplateConfiguration configuration, BindingResult result) {
    model.addAttribute("report", getReport()); //get your data

    if(result.hasErrors()){
       return ERROR_VIEW; 
    }


    return "reportView";
}
```

### See also

- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/pdf-view.html
- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/bean-name-view-resolver.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added an answer.